# Mercury binding agents which cross the blood brain barrier

Tags: biochemistry

The two substances I have come across are cilantro and lipoic acid. How effective would either of them be? Are there any other agents known which produce the desired results?

Comment: What are your desired results? Are you looking for something that will enter the brain, grab a mercury atom, then leave the brain carrying the mercury atom out?

Comment: Yes of course. I am interested in chelation therapy to remove mercury from my brain and then out of my body.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0162013413003358